# Single Spring boot for multiple RDBMS databases

Tags: database, spring-boot

I have a requirement that I need to connect a small API to an Oracle DB for few GET ops. Now in dev since there is only 1 instance, it's quite easy to provide. But when it comes to production, the DBs are located in 5 different countries and hence are 5 different instances (All of them are exactly the same except for the data). My idea is to run them via application.properties with active profile and then connect them to application-{active-profile}.properties. Something like below:

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=DB1
spring.application.name=demo
```

application-DB1.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host1:port/SID
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public class DBConfiguration {

    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Profile("dev")
    @Bean
    public String devDBConnection(){
        System.out.println("URL:"+getUrl());
        System.out.println("username:"+getUsername());
        System.out.println("password:"+getPassword());
        return "DEV DB connection";
    }

    @Profile("uat")
    @Bean
    public String uatDBConnection() {
        System.out.println("URL:" + getUrl());
        System.out.println("username:" + getUsername());
        System.out.println("password:" + getPassword());
        return "UAT DB connection";
    }
}
```

So when I have to enable the API for another DB, say DB-3 , all I have to do is change the active.profile=DB3 and create a new file application-DB3.properties.

Does this seem a standard practice or is there an way to do this more efficiently ?

Comment: You want to connect all databases at once or just one when you start the application

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Just one when I start the application. So it would be basically one API per DB. So 5 API instances for the 5 DBs.

Comment: But then you don't need profiles. Simply pass the DB connection parameters as environment variables. How do you start the app?

Comment: I will use java -jar in a nohup script. So, yes it would make sense to pass those parameters along with the command. Just wanted to understand what are the good practices around such a setup.

Comment: I added a recommendation as the answer. Please accept it if you find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice is to pass such configuration as environment variables or system properties.

So you don't need to change the code/configuration when these variables change.